# Need to understand my error when creating a bank account in python

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have a project to create a bank account class, add methods and increase/decrease the account holder's balance using the deposit and withdraw method. Here is the code:

```
class BankAccount():

    interest = 0.01

    def __init__(self, acct_name, acct_num, balance):
        self.acct_num = acct_num
        self.acct_name = acct_name
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Make a deposit into the account."""
        self.balance = self.balance + int(amount)

    def withdrawal(self, amount):
        """Make a withdrawal from the account."""
        self.balance = self.balance - amount

    def add_interest(self, interest):
        """Add interest to the account holder's account."""
        self.balance = self.balance * interest

    def acct_info(self):
        print("Account Name - " + self.acct_name + ":" + " Account Balance - " + int(self.balance) + ":" + " Account Number - " + self.acct_num + ".")

acct1 = BankAccount('Moses Dog', '554874D', 126.90)
acct1.deposit(500)
acct1.acct_info()
print(" ")

acct2 = BankAccount('Athena Cat', '554573D', '$1587.23')
acct2.acct_info()
print(" ")

acct3 = BankAccount('Nick Rat', '538374D', '$15.23')
acct3.acct_info()
print(" ")

acct4 = BankAccount('Cassie Cow', '541267D', '$785.23')
acct4.acct_info()   
print(" ")

acct5 = BankAccount('Sam Seagull', '874401D', '$6.90')
acct5.acct_info()
print(" ")
```

When I call the acct1.deposit(500) method, I get "can't convert int object to string implicitly".

If I change the int(amount) to str(amount) and run it, it appends 500 to the current balance.

Any help would be appreciated. I understand if there is any criticism. I have googled but I am not following completely.

Comment: `'$1587.23'` is not a number.

Comment: ok, i changed that, but numbers that end in zero aren't showing properly as account balances.

Comment: `" Account Balance - " + int(self.balance)` - what do you think is happening there?

Comment: i want it to show the number associated with the user's account balance, but it the error in my code has it attempting to convert it to a string. i don't see where i made that mistake.

Comment: The error message says "Can't convert 'int' object to str *implicitly*". When you try to add a string and an integer, that's the error you get, because Python won't *implicitly* convert the int into a string for concatenation. You have to perform the conversion explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some hints:

```
>>> '$300.10' + 500  # adding a string to an int
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

>>> 300.10 + 500  # adding a float to an int
800.1

>>> '$300.10' + str(500)   # When using strings
'$300.10500'

>>> print(300.10)        # loss of zero
300.1

>>> print('${:.2f}'.format(300.10))  # formatting
$300.10
```

Make sure you are using correct types for your balance, deposit, and withdrawal values.  Use formatting to preserve the number of digits past the decimal point.

See [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: ok, i got that portion fixed. Thank you for all of your help. I'm trying to add a 500.00 deposit to an account, but my program is only showing the initial amount. I apologize for all of the questions, but this is kicking my ass.

Answer (score 0):

in acct_info() try changing it to :

```
def acct_info(self):
  print("Account Name - "+self.acct_name + ":"+" Account Balance - "+  str(self.balance) +":" +" Account Number - "+self.acct_num + ".")
```